# Is there a reason for naming prefix Xl for Enum Classes in Microsoft Libraries?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

The enum classes for all Microsoft libraries use the Xl prefix convention in c#

Example:

- XlMousePointer
- XlColorIndex
- XlRgbColor

Is there a reason for this? is this a Microsoft only convention?

Comment: Because they are used with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the use of the "Xl" prefix convention in enum classes is specific to Microsoft libraries in the context of C#. This convention is commonly seen in Microsoft Office development...The "Xl" prefix stands for "Excel" and it helps avoid naming conflicts with other libraries or user-defined enum values that may have similar names.

For example:

**XlMousePointer** represents different mouse pointer styles used in Excel;
**XlColorIndex** represents the color palette index used in Excel;
**XlRgbColor** represents colors specified in the RGB format used in Excel...

For general enum classes you should follow conventions: use singular nouns (excluding flags enum), PascalCase, avoid abbreviations and be consistent!

You can read more about naming guidelines here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#naming-enumerations

Comment: is there any preferred notation for a general enum class?

Comment: singular nouns, Pascal Case, avoid abbreviations and be consistent!

Comment: Please add this to the answer, including any possible explanation for the prefix that libraries/projects use for the enum classes. Thank you